# Laravel 5 перевод и база данных

Tags: laravel

Язык меняю на странице путем смены `app.locales`.
Вывод использую в виде `{{ trans('nomer.feedback') }}`.
Подскажите как быть с базой? БД на русском, создать вторую на английском, и при смены локали брать данные с другой, подскажите как это реализовать, или есть более интересное решение?

Comment: если использовать https://github.com/stichoza/google-translate-php

Answer (score 1):

Для таких переводов в БД. Я использую этот пакет

https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable